# How can i automatically turn on notifications for facebook post using graph api

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, social-networking

I have a facebook post id , to get any notification for this post , i must go to the upper right corner of post and press and select "turn on notification" option

now , how can i do it automatically using facebook api or any other ways , how can is call a method or something and give it the post id then it turn notifications on.

thank you

Comment: there is no way to access or set notifications with the api

Comment: Is there another way ?

Comment: weird question after the comment "there is no way"...